FCM se descontinuara el 20 de junio?
Estaba revisando mi correo y me encontré con un mensaje que dice: "in 20 June, 2024 20, 2024 the legacy Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) APIs will be discontinued.".
Según revisé se va a descontinuar el envío de notificaciones por medio de FCM, la versión antigua. ¿Pero quería saber si esto tendrá un impacto en Expo? ¿Ya que yo uso él para enviar push notifications por medio del API de expo, afecta a este?
